# Mysql improve sampling query speed

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 3,000,000 records.I tried to randomly extract 300,000 records using the following method,but it takes about 7 minutes.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `class`='faq' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 300000
```

I want to improve the speed of random extraction, what should I do?
Mysql version is 5.6.

Comment: What about having only few columns with index on those columns and on column 'class' also.

Comment: Do you have index for `class` ?

Comment: class is not an index field

Comment: Well try adding an index for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast)

Comment: RAND() just ain't that fast. Can you live with it?

Answer (score 0):

The cost is most likely due to sorting all the matching data.  You don't specify how many rows match the condition, so this sort is likely to be some fraction of 3,000,000 rows.

If you can deal with approximately 300,000, you can use sampling logic in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM t
      WHERE class = 'faq'
     ) x
WHERE t.class = 'faq' AND
      rand() < (300000 / cnt);
```

To be more precise, you can take a slightly larger random sample and then use `order by`/`limit`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM t
      WHERE class = 'faq'
     ) x
WHERE t.class = 'faq' AND
      rand() < (300000 / cnt) * 1.1
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 300000;
```

Comment: I am of a long held understanding that MySQL `RAND` is a very inefficient and slow process and where at all possible it's better to simply avoid it and / or pass the full data set to the output and let the output (PHP, etc.) pick random results in a faster, more efficient manner. Maybe MySQL 8.0 revolutionised this? hah

Comment: @Martin . . . Sorting is expensive.  I'm not aware that `rand()` is "very inefficient".  In general, it is better to reduce the amount of data passed to applications and `rand()` is one way to do that.